# bootstrap tab changes size with wide images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I made a tabbed page using tab-pane class in Bootstrap v3. The tabs menu on the left, tab contents on the right. These together are in the middle of the page, and then the rest of the page is background.

Whenever I place an image inside tab-contents that is wider than a certain size, it makes that tab a little narrower than the tabs without images that wide. Therefore when I switch from one tab with wide image to one without, a very visible width change occurs. Interestingly, all tabs with wide images have the same a-little-narrower width, and so do all tabs without wide images.

To illustrate, this tab

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="dummy">
    <img src="assets/img/dummy.png">
    <h4>lorem ipsum</h4>
</div><!-- Tab Profile -->
```

looks a little narrower than this tab

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="dummy">
    <h4>lorem ipsum</h4>
</div><!-- Tab Profile -->
```

Also, it doesn't matter whether I use `class="img-responsive"` or not. The problem remains the same.

I am not sure if i could make my point thoroughly. So if more info is needeed, let me know.

**EDIT: a bootply version of the site:
http://www.bootply.com/eYaZAWwPdJ**

Comment: Would you be able to throw up some of the code for you tabs on [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new) so we can get a better idea and have something to work with?

Comment: sure here: http://www.bootply.com/SpiyE2lxux But as i mentioned above tabs dont work there, although they work nicely on the site.

Comment: Here is a bootply with the the tabs working so others can see as well: [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/eYaZAWwPdJ) . The reason they weren't working was because you were not initiating them via the javascript. With that in mind, I'm still unable to see the problem? The tabs seem to change correctly

Comment: Thanks a lot for making it work. So the problem is: you see how CV tab and Contact tab (the ones without wide images) have a uniform slightly wider width, and the other tabs with wide images (about, research, teaching) have a uniform narrower width.

Comment: By the way, i just realized the problem is gone on Internet Explorer. But is there on Chrome. And somehow, on Firefox, the website has the problem but your bootply fork doesn't. On Chrome, both the website and bootply are problematic. On IE, no problem for both. Can that be an issue related to different jquery versions?

Comment: Okay, let me take another look and I'll see if I can update my answer

Comment: [continue discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90238/discussion-between-ryan-fitzgerald-and-can-celik).

Answer (score 1):

So after taking a look at your code, as I mentioned above, there were a few issues that I came across. As far as I can tell, it seems to be working, but if that's not the case let me know and I can take another look.

**A couple of things to note**

You can activate tabs individually using a number of selectors:

```
$('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show') // Select tab by name
$('#myTab a:first').tab('show') // Select first tab
$('#myTab a:last').tab('show') // Select last tab
$('#myTab li:eq(2) a').tab('show') // Select third tab (0-indexed)
```

You can also just initiate them all at once via javascript:

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

Alternatively, you can activate a tab or pill navigation without writing any JavaScript by simply specifying `data-toggle="tab"` or `data-toggle="pill"` on an element.

Also, looking at your code, you were missing some attributes as defined in the examples from Bootstrap docs:

1. On the main ul: `<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">`
2. On individual tab list elements: `<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>`

After changing and including the above, the Bootply seems to change tabs without any weird sizing issues with images, however I'm not sure if a problematic image has been included or not. If one hasn't been included, update the Bootply and I can take a look again.

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/eYaZAWwPdJ

For more information on Bootstrap tabs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I will take a look at your suggestions. But the bootply still has the problem on Chrome